# how to encode a string in javascript and decode the string in java

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I need to encode a string in jsp using javascript, and send this string to the spring controller and decode this string in java, am currently doing something like this

javascript - in jsp

```
 if(/^.%[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(comments) == false) {
       // alert('Your comments contains illegal characters.');
        var encodedComments = encodeURI(comments);
        //alert(encodedComments);
    } else{
        var encodedComments = comments;
        //alert(encodedComments);
        }
```

In the controller

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9-/.^%$/ ]*";
        boolean m = Pattern.matches(regex, data[6]);
        if (m == true) {
           System.out.println("There is a sp. character in the string");
           try {
            comments = URLDecoder.decode(data[6], "UTF-8");
            logger.info("The decoded string comments============>>>>>>>>>>>"+comments);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no sp. char.");
                comments = data[6];
                logger.info("The remarks with no special characters is ============>>>>>>>>>>>"+comments);
        }
```

for ex: I gave comments in a textarea: like score 6.08%, the encoded string is coming correctly, but the decoded string is not working, it is just printing score 6 that's all. How do I decode the string in java encoded in javascript??
am I missing something here??

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need to decode in Java

Comment: yes I need to decode in java

Answer (score 0):

at javascript side you need always do encoding via [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) at java side you need always do decoding, if reading directly from QUERY_STRING, if you're reading from request.getParameter - decoding is not needed at all

Comment: yes and sending the variables from jsp to controller in a queryString separated with &&, In this case can I just get it as request.getParameter(data[6]) directly, no need to decode this??

Comment: what do you mean "from jsp to controller"? arguments should be separated with `&`

Comment: I am sending submitting form, and sending variables like this var dataId = var1 + "&&" + var2 + "&&" + var3 + "&&" + comments;
this.form.action = '${Url}/' + dataId;

Comment: @sailaja but proper way it `${Url}/?' dataId;` and use single &

Comment: ok sure, I will use the single &, how do I decode this comments variable in java code, if I enter'score 67%', it is displaying as it is, but when I give 'score 6.07%' it is showing 'score 6' that's all. How to handle such a scenario